# Passing function via props from Parent to Child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, components

I am having an issue where I'm trying to pass a function(updateEvents) via props from my App.js file to a NumberOfEvents.js file. I passed the same function to another component with no issues. However, when I try on the NumberOfEvents file, I get the following error:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSgt5.png)
Please help!!!

Here is the Parent:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EventList from './EventList';
import CitySearch from './CitySearch';
import NumberOfEvents from './NumberOfEvents';
import { extractLocations, getEvents } from './api';

import './nprogress.css';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    events: [],
    locations: [],
    numberOfEvents: 32
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true;

    getEvents().then((events) => {
      if (this.mounted) {
        this.setState({
          events: events.slice(0, this.state.numberOfEvents),
          locations: extractLocations(events)
        });
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  updateEvents = (location, eventCount) => {
    this.mounted = true;
    getEvents().then((events) => {
      const locationEvents = (location === 'all')
        ? events
        : events.filter((event) => event.location === location);
      this.setState({
        events: locationEvents,
        numberOfEvents: eventCount,
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CitySearch
          locations={this.state.locations} updateEvents={this.updateEvents} />
        <EventList
          events={this.state.events} />
        <NumberOfEvents
          numberOfEvents={this.state.numberOfEvents}
          updateEvents={this.updateEvents} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here is the Child:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class NumberOfEvents extends Component {
  state = {
    numberOfEvents: 32
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      numberOfEvents: value,
    });
    this.props.updateEvents('', value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        className="number"
        value={this.state.numberOfEvents}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
    )
  }
}

export default NumberOfEvents;
```

Comment: what do you see if you console log this.props in the child?

Comment: @richardsefton It just console logs an empty object {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure this will help ...In Your Parent Component , inside return statement when passing the updateEvents Prop, try passing it as arrow function like this ....

`updateEvents={ () =>  this.updateEvents() } />`

Comment: I tried that too! Still the same error. :/

Comment: Pass the necessary params inside this.updateEvents( )

Comment: That seems to have made a difference! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try adding a constructor to the child component

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        numberOfEvents: 32   
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try that, it still gives me the same error, but the console logs this.props as:
{ numberOfEvents: 32, updateEvents: [Function (anonymous)] }

Comment: But it looks like the logging of { numberOfEvents: 32, updateEvents: [Function (anonymous)] } is happening in App.js, and it's still an empty object in NumberOfEvents :(